# nuxt-laravel project with Sanctum auth works on localhost but doesn't work after deployment

Tags: proxy, nuxt.js, laravel-sanctum

my Nuxtjs project located inside on frontend directory and Laravel inside on the backend. To login, fetching user information, logout, and fetching other data like articles it works on localhost. But after deployment just it can fetch and display all articles or a specific article. It isn't able to dose login.
This is the situation in firefox after login:

> Cookie “auth.strategy” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite” attribute set to “None” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

I configured nuxt.config.js like this:

```
modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy'
  ],
  proxy: {
    '/api/': {
      target: 'http://bbackend-laravel.com/api/',
      pathRewrite: { '^/api/': '/' }
    }
  },
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      'laravelSanctum': {
        provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
        url: 'http://bbackend-laravel.com',
        endpoints:{
          login:{
            url:'/api/login'
          },
          logout:{
            url:'/api/logout'
          }
        }
      },
    }
  },
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://bbackend-laravel.com',
    credentials: true,
    proxy: true,
  },
```

and login code is like this:

```
  methods: {
    login() {
      try {
      const loginResult = this.$auth.loginWith('laravelSanctum', {
        data: {
          email: 's.shamshiri@gmail.com',
          password: 'password'
        }
      })
      console.log('loginResult===',loginResult);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error Response', e.response)
      }
    }
  }
```

this is cors.php configuration:

```
   'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie','login','logout'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

I don't know where is my mistake that I can't do log in after deployment.

Comment: When you deploy it in production, you should change Axios base URL and auth laravelSanctum URL to the domain of your website.

Comment: oh,sorry @JenuelGanawed . it was my mistake when I write my question. I had already it. my problem persists. please notice again to codes.